# Discontinuity of a function regarding limits

Tags: limits

Let'say a function is $f(x) = -2$, when $x<1$, $f(x) = x-3$ when $x>1$, and $f(x) = 10$ when $x = 1$. At $x =1$ the function is discontinuous, I am not sure why though. The right hand limits and left hand limits are the same and there is a value when $x = 1$.

Not sure if this is a silly question, I'm just not understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of continuity at a point $a$ is
$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a), $$
which is not the case for your function at $a=1$.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if that seemed silly.